# Applying font to a paragraph

Tags: fonts, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

I am doing my phd thesis and I want to apply a different font but only to the paragraphs of my document, I mean: only to some parts of the document. How could I do this?

Moreover, does anyone know what font family this is? I can't find it anywhere (if anyone knows of any other "light/fancy" font, please let me know).

[image]

**A solution:**

Example using `lmss` font family. At the top of the file:

```
\newenvironment{lmss}{\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont}{\par}
```

and then we can use `\begin` and `\end` wherever. Example:

```
This is a sentence using the regular font.
\begin{lmss}
And this is a sentence using lmss font.
\end{lmss}
Again, another sentence using the regular font.
```

Comment: your question is not very clear, almost all text is in a paragraph, normally you would set the document default font for that, and have heading etc  fonts specified elsewhere. For the font in the image, if you have that as pdf, the font menu of your viewer, or `pdffonts` commandline program will report the fonts used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle doesn't it look like a lighter version of CMU-Serif itself? (Just guessing)

Comment: Yes I suspect it is the default cm but see if OP confirms

Comment: run in a terminal `pdffonts <doc>.pdf`  or use the Adobe Reader and lists the fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your original question, there are various ways in which you can change fonts with LaTeX. Here is a list of a few such ways with examples.

---

## Engine-agnostic ways

The default font-family of PDFLaTeX is Computer Modern, but this font itself has various flavors, e.g., bold, italic, typewriter, sans-serif. The default font is Serif. The moment you decide to change it, technically you are changing the font. (Though some of them are known as weights, i.e., bold, in LaTeX you essentially change font and nothing else.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]

{%
  \sffamily
  \lipsum[1-1]%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

There are some fonts provided along with LaTeX (a comprehensive list can be found [here](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/)) which can be used for the entire document like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{jkp}\selectfont
\lipsum[1-1]

{%
  \sffamily
  \lipsum[1-1]%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3]

(Here I have used the KP fonts for demonstration. Notice that the sans family also gets changed to the Sans font of KP family with `\sffamily`.)

or locally like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]

{%
  \fontfamily{jkp}\selectfont
  % \sffamily % Uncomment if you want sans family.
  \lipsum[1-1]%
}
\end{document}
```

## Unicode fonts

LaTeX is a pre-Unicode software, hence the default PDFLaTeX doesn't support Unicode encoded input, but XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX were precisely developed to support it and thus now you can use your nomral Unicode-based fonts with LaTeX too. For that you need to `\usepackage`[`{fontspec}`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec). For demonstration I have used [EB Garamond](https://ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\myunicodefont}{EBGaramond-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]

{%
  \myunicodefont
  \lipsum[1-1]%
}
\end{document}
```

(Don't forget to run this code with `xelatex` or `lualatex`; otherwise boom!)

[image: 6]

Comment: Tysm, I finally made a new enviroment. That way I can use `\begin` and `\end` in any part f the document. I´ve updated the question.